# Find and replace Using statements with Resharper Find and replace

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

Using Resharper's 'Search with Pattern' mode, I've been trying to do the simple task of finding and replacing a using statement, but it doesn't appear to let me do this, it complains that the "Pattern is ambiguous".

What's the problem here?

I realise I can use Visual Studio's own find and replace tool, but I have a lot of files to change, and I know from experience that Resharper gives me more control over finding and replacing code (and also because I'm curious as to what the issue is here).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Search by Pattern" is a powerful tool for searching by regex or other patterns.

The prompt is due to the engine interpreting your query as a very open-ended Regular Expression.

For a basic search & replace such as yours, I would use the built-in tools which Visual Studio provides.

Additional and very important note: The warning is actually "Pattern is ambiguos [sic]"

Comment: I'm guessing that last part was sarcasm?

Comment: It was sarcasm, and out of place. (But I found it amusing)